# Airflow SubDagOperator deadlock

Tags: airflow

I'm running into a problem where a DAG composed of several SubDagOperators hangs indefinitely.

The setup:
Using CeleryExecutor. For the purposes of this example, let's say we have one worker which can run five tasks concurrently. 
The DAG I'm running into problems with runs several SubDagOperators in parallel. For illustration purposes, consider the following graph, where every node is a SubDagOperator:
[image: DAG that stops making progress]

The problem: The DAG will stop making progress in the high-parallelism part of the DAG. The root cause seems to be that the top-level SubDagOperators take up all five of the slots available for running tasks, so none of the sub-tasks inside of those SubDagOperators are able to run. Those subtasks get stuck in the queued state and no one makes progress.

It was a bit surprising to me that the SubDagOperator tasks would compete with their own subtasks for task running slots, but it makes sense to me now. Are there best practices around writing SubDagOperators that I am violating?

My plan is to work around this problem by creating a custom operator to encapsulate the tasks that are currently encapsulated inside the SubDagOperators. I was wondering if anyone had advice on whether it was advisable to create an operator composed of other operators?

Comment: From what I understand the way to deal with concurrency deadlocks like this is to use `pool`s, but I don't have enough experience with this to write up an answer.

Comment: Your image appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like SubDagOperator should be avoided because it causes this deadlock issue. I ultimately found that for my use case, I was best served by writing my own custom `BaseOperator` subclass to do the tasks I was doing inside SubDagOperator. Writing the operator class was much easier than I expected.

Comment: Suggested read [Fixing SubDagOperator Deadlock in Airflow](https://medium.com/@team_24989/fixing-subdagoperator-deadlock-in-airflow-6c64312ebb10)

Comment: Can you provide an example of your new Operator?